Import package on VsCode doesnt works
When I create a Java project in VsCode and organize the files in package, when I try to import the packages, I get an error. but in netbeans, when I create it with maven and create the folders to separate, the import works. I wanted to know how I can make my vscode work
I try to create the program with maven on vscode but doesn't works, i tried to creat folder manually but doesn't work too.

Does your build on plain command line with Maven works? Also interesting which JDK, Maven Version etc. do you use?
